# Change bootstrap-div border color with javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am trying to change the border color of a div but it does not work when using bootstrap class on the div. How can I change this border color with javascript?

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="p-1 border bg-light" align="center" id="101">No</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("101").style.border = "1px solid #ff0000"; // Change in not made
    document.getElementById("101").innerHTML = "Yes"; // Change is made
</script>
```

Comment: try this `1px solid #ff0000 !important`

Comment: Why did you even use ```.border``` if you want to create own styles for border ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use setAttribute to set style in javascript. I have added **!important** here as bootstrap has class border which is overriding inline CSS. To give high priority to inline I have added **!important**.

```js
document.getElementById("101").setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid #ff00ff !important');// Change is  made now
    document.getElementById("101").innerHTML = "Yes"; // Change is made
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="p-1 border bg-light" align="center" id="101">No</div>
```

As @penguin suggested, we can use cssText as well.

```js
document.getElementById("101").style.cssText +=  'border:1px solid red!important';// Change is  made now
    document.getElementById("101").innerHTML = "Yes"; // Change is made
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="p-1 border bg-light" align="center" id="101">No</div>
```

Comment: appending to the `style.cssText` might be a better option

Comment: Thanks @Penguin, I have updated the answer with cssText as well.

Comment: One last suggestion: instead of setting it using `=`, append it using `+=`. (like `a.style.cssText += "color: #f00 !important;"`) That will retain other styles also, so that way changing it doesnt overwrite it. This is the advantage of the cssText over setting the style attribute

Comment: Ops, that's correct. I checked that in setAttribute but not in cssText